# Programmatically change constraint on a UILabel breaks layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UILabel with two constraints. One of the constraints I activate and the other I leave disabled. I have a button which disables the first constraint and activates the second constraint. Then when tapped a second time, disables the second constraint and re-activates the first constraint. Tapping this button the first time works as intended. The UILabel including all other UILabels constrained to it, moves to a different position. However, when tapping on the button to move it back, the layout breaks. The UILabel moves to a position that's almost to where it was before, but all the other UILabels constrained to it stay put and don't move back to their original position.

Here's the function that handles activating the constraints.

```
- (void)tapOnce:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (_constraintLabelOne.isActive) {
        [_constraintLabelOne setActive:NO];
        [_constraintLabelTwo setActive:YES];
    } else {
        [_constraintLabelTwo setActive:NO];
        [_constraintLabelOne setActive:YES];
    }
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

The constraints look like this.

```
_constraintLabelOne = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myLabel
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:topView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:6];
_constraintLabelTwo = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myLabel
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:topView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:20];
```

The other labels constrained to `myLabel` are stuck in the second position after `tapOnce` has been called the first time. Why don't they move back to their initial position after `myLabel` constraints have been updated?

I've attached a screenshot with a drawing of the current behavior. The blue box represents `topView`. The magenta box represents `myLabel`. The first screen is before calling `tapOnce`. The middle screen is after calling `tapOnce` one time. The right screen is after calling `tapOnce` twice.

[image]

Comment: What is the _desired_ behavior?

Comment: The desired behavior is for the screen to look like the far left after calling `tapOnce` a second time. The layout should never look like the far right screen.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the far left screen was the starting point. You said "The first screen is before calling tapOnce". If it isn't, what did the screen look like before you called `tapOnce` for the first time? Can you show what the effect of `tapOnce` is supposed to be, i.e. before and after? Or are you saying that one tap causes us to go from the first screen to the second and the second tap should cause us to go from the second back to the first?

Comment: I'm saying the desired effect is that one tap causes us to go from the first screen to the second, and the second tap should cause us to go from the second back to the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. What was happening was the UILabel's height was not constrained, so when the second constraint was deactivated and the first constraint reactivated the height automatically increased (see image below). To fix this I had to manually constrain the height of all of my view items. If anyone has a better solution please post it as I'd prefer not to manually set the height for each item because that might cause the layouts to break on different devices.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Thanks to siburb for pointing out the `Content Hugging Priority` property for UI Elements. The root of my issue was that this property was not being set which allowed for my UILabel's height to expand. The solution was to set this property to a value of 750 or higher.

```
[myLabel setContentHuggingPriority:750 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
```

Comment: You don't have to manually constrain the heights. You should just increase the `Content Hugging Priority` of the labels so that they're more assertive in not expanding beyond their intrinsic content size. Try something over 750 initially, but you may need to increase to "required"  or 1000.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I wasn't aware of the `Content Hugging Priority` property on UI elements. This was definitely the root of my problem, thank you.

Comment: @Michael If you now have a solution please revise your answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would do this is to set the `priority` of one of the constraints lower so it is "optional" e.g. `UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh`, or even higher e.g. 999.

You can then have both constraints active at the same time, and the required constraint will take priority.

To set it up, set the required constraint for the default state, and the optional constraint for the button press state.

You can start with both constraints active, and then when the button is pressed, you just disable (set `constraint.active = NO`) the required constraint and the other one will take priority. When the button is pressed again, you just re-enable the required constraint.

Comment: I just tried it this way and I'm still experiencing the same issue. When I re-enable the required constraint, all the other items in the view stay put and the UILabel moves to a point that's in between the item below it and the `topView` item.